# Issue with Entity Framework class being returned via Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, web-services, entity-framework

I've implemented a web service and I am calling it via ajax. 

*Note: My entities have been made for an entity framework code first purpose.*

My ajax looks as follows:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "/MyProject/MyService.svc/GetEntity",
   data: "entityID=1",
   dataType: "json",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   success: AjaxSucceeded,
   error: function (msg, status, extra) {
      alert(status + " - " + extra);
   }
 });
```

AjaxSucceeded is simply a function with the data variable where I am simply logging the data in the console.

My GetEntity function currently looks like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public MyEntity GetEntity(int entityID)
{
    AccessObject accessObject = new AccessObject("MyConnectionString");

    MyEntity theEntity = accessObject.GetByID(entityID);

    return theEntity;
}
```

I have tested this with a class created purposefully for testing and it worked as expected (for example, I created a MyEntity class within the web service that was very simple, a couple of properties and no other methods etc.).

The problems arises when I return an entity that I have made for code first Entity Framework. It doesn't work, the web service function is called multiple times and then an error appears in the console stating "Failed to load resource" referring to my service function.

For reference, here is my entity:

```
[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
public class MyEntity
{
    #region Properties

    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public bool SomeBoolean { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string Description { get; set;}

    #endregion

    #region Relationships

    public virtual SomeOtherEntity OtherEntity { get; set; }

    #endregion

}
```

I have only set the ID to be DataMember for testing but still no success.

Could anyone point me in the correct direction? I know the web service works because other functions work and if I set up a local (within the web service) class it will return that with no issues. So I'm of the assumption that it has something to do with the entity framework attributes? I may be wrong but that's all I can imagine.

Thank you for your time.

Oh also, for reference, my service class has the following attributes:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

Comment: I tried not to make that question in to an essay. Sorry about the length of it.

Comment: Is your wcf service an "ajax-enabled wcf service"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simply Entities aren't really built for serialization. My advice would be to create a DTO, map the relevant properties across and pass that over the wire instead e.g.

```
public class EntityDto
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    ...
}

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public EntityDto MyEntity(int entityId)
{
    AccessObject accessObject = new AccessObject("MyConnectionString");
    MyEntity theEntity = accessObject.GetByID(entityID);
    return new EntityDto()
    {
        ID = theEntity.ID,
        Description = theEntity.Description,
        ...
    };
}
```

Comment: @ThePower You should never return anything from a web service that isn't just a DTO.  Your web service is a contract that you can't change without immediately breaking clients.  Returning your entities means you can't change them, but if you have a DTO you can change your entity and just update the mapping, thus keeping your clients happy.

Comment: @ThePower just to add to what Andy said, you also need to consider the fact that entities have loads of properties/data which is irrelevant to the consumer, therefore, your using unnecessary bandwidth. A rule of thumb is - only send over the wire exactly what the consumer needs. Also, having a different model keeps a clear separation of concerns i.e. your entity is used for persistence & your DTO is used for passing data between tiers/layers. Considering this is a public facing API, like Andy mentioned, this gives you the flexibility to change your backend without affecting your API.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the information guys. I wasn't approaching it as an API style web service. It's more for a specific section of the site, where things needs to work on the client side and I needed to make a few calls and get some data out for display. But now thinking of it as a public facing API I fully understand, it also opens up the opportunity of an API too! Thanks